# Why is ST_Contour returning error "band number must be between 1 and 0 inclusive", when value passed to the function is 1?

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, geoalchemy2, postgis-raster

I am trying to use ST_Contour() to create contour lines from a raster stored in db.

When I pass:

```
SELECT ST_Contour(my_raster_column, 1, 5, 0) FROM my_schema.my_table WHEN my_other_column IS NOT NULL
```

(I am using async python with sqlalchemy/geoalchemy2 and asyncpg) it returns an internal server error that says:
"RASTER_Contour: band number must be between 1 and 0 inclusive"

There is only one band in my raster, and as I understand it, that should correspond to and input of '1' for the 'bandnumber' argument.

I have tried everything i can think of including:
using explicit type casts,
'bandnumber'=0, (same error)
'bandnumber'=1.0, (same error)
'bandnumber'=0.1 (this one causes a different error: "function st_contour(raster, numeric, integer, integer) does not exist")

Comment: Reading the source code, the line which generates that error is `elog(ERROR, "%s: band number must be between 1 and %u inclusive", __func__, num_bands);` If it says between "between 1 and 0 inclusive" then that means that the raster has zero bands. Are you sure your raster has one band?

Comment: Checked the rasters right after posting this... Yes, apparently after running ST_Clip on them they were empty. I'm not sure why ST_Clip would delete all bands from the raster without raising any sort of error, but it did, and adding the raster data without clipping first fixed the error ST_Contour was throwing, it runs now, but returns nothing. So, now I need to figure out why ST_Contour is returning no results.